# SQL Database mapping and other data retrieval sources

Tags: c#, sql, excel, mapping

I have an engineering application developed in c# and I need the following component/tool.

My application for each of its calculation cycles should read a set of parameters as input. Some of the potential customers keep those input parameters in excel files, others in sql databases and others in forms (paper or digital) or even other not known yet.

So, for each deployment,  I need to customize the "input reader" module to comply with a specific requirement and at best I may be able to reuse some code.
I need a module like an sql mapper tool to be integrated in my application so I will be able to construct a specification set (using eg. sql or QBE) to gather data from sources like sql, excel files or other and map them to my own internal dataset for the input parameters.

Thanks in advance for your time and support.

Regards,
semag

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: For all databases, it should be source connection agnostic. My case now is for Sql Server

Comment: To be more specific, think about embedding linqpad in your application as a runtime tool to connect to any data source.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get away with using an ODBC connection, which would allow you to use stock ado.net (and by extension, an ORM of your choice) top of your specific datastore.

Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

With respect to being able to cope with any specific implementation, it sounds like you may want to check out the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to split any implementation-specific parsing into its own component.